# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition not returning callback for FIREFOX 74.0

Tags: javascript

I try and run this code in my react app on local host on firefox V74.0
edit: there are two functions callbacks, also i expanded my entire code, as opposed to the just navigator line of code.

```
   function callback(position){
        comment.pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          long: position.coords.longitude,
        }

        DB.postNewThread(comment);
    }

 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(callback,function(error){
           if(error){
   // actually this function is only ever called if there is an error i think

// i settle for a small approximation with this particular API called api.ipstack.com
             fetch(geouri)
             .then(resp=>resp.json())
             .then(l=>{
               const obj = {
                 coords: l
               }
               callback(obj)
             })
             .catch(function(e)
              console.log(e);
               alert("You can not be using HTTPS if your browser doesnt support native geo locator. Update Firefox or Chrome")
             });
             console.log(error);
           }
         });
```

the callback function is never executed even when i  put it in the in console. the dialoge pops up and i click allow location.Navigator.geolocation is a truthy object.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are running into an error ?

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success[, error[, [options]])
```

You can add another callback function for errors.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
    console.log("GOT THE POS",position);
}, function(error) {
    console.log(error)
});
```

Comment: The problem was linux mint default firefox doesnt have an high enough  version which made it so it appeared to have navigator but it doesnt. this error function helped.